# Print out NSDictionary key - value pair format?

Tags: ios, nsarray

Wants to print NSDictioanary like key = value, key2 = value2, key3 = value3

Is it possible inline way?
Value should have apostrof if it is string.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I mean do you want to log the Dictionary in the console in that format ?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
print(nameOfYourDictionary)
```

In Objective-C:

```
NSLog(nameOfYourDictionary);
```